# Adding a custom message box in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a customized and small info/message box similar to what you find in [**this site**](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/07/01/big-join-update-makes-capturing-screencasts-devices-breeze-can-even-automate-uploads-youtube/) under **what's new** area.

Well, I'm not an expert in coding but I can get along if there's hint as to how. I have even tried searching google, wordpress plugins... etc but couldn't find what I was searching for. Or maybe I'm searching with incorrect words...

Any advise as to how?

Comment: its pure CSS styling, you don't need a plugin for that, https://jsfiddle.net/8eh0ket6/

Comment: This is great! But how do I add it into WP. So, that I can use it whenever required on a post?

Comment: put the HTML code on the page you want it to show and the CSS on your css file, you actually need some basic knowledge of worpdress, html & CSS to modify your site.